# Webmethods(Software AG Designer 9.12): Parse Huge Flat File

Tags: stream, webmethods

We are not able to parse a huge flat file. (size 80-100MB)

-We are getting the file via getFile. We were able to pick up the file as a STREAM
-We tried to use streamToByes options but got an error message JavaHeapSpace. We already maximize the heap space and still the same.
-What we are currently doing is, getFile>convertToValues and thats it..

Could you please advise how to do it? our plan is:

I would like to parse this big flat file delimited by ";" and then tokenize it. However, using string:tokenize cannot accept Stream files.

Answer (score 1):

The WM doc talks about that :

> By default, Integration Server processes all flat files in the same manner, regardless of
>   their size. Integration Server receives a flat file and keeps the file content **in memory
>   during processing**. However, if you receive large files, Integration Server can encounter
>   problems when working with these files because the system does not have enough
>   memory to hold the entire parsed file.
>   If some or all of the flat files that you process encounter problems because of memory
>   constraints, **you can set the iterator variable in the pub.flatFile:convertToValues service to true** to process top level records (children of the document root) in the flat file
>   schema one at a time. After all child records of the top level record are parsed, the pub.flatFile:convertToValues service returns and the iterator moves to the top level of the next record in the schema, until all records are parsed. This parsing should be done in a flow service using a REPEAT step where each time the pub.flatFile:convertToValues service returns, the results are mapped and dropped from the pipeline to conserve memory. If the results were kept in the pipeline, out–of–memory errors might occur.
>   The pub.flatFile:converToValues service generates an output object (ffIterator variable) that encapsulates and keeps track of the input records during processing. When all input
>   data has been parsed, this object becomes null. When the ffIterator variable is null, you
>   should use an EXIT step to exit from the REPEAT step and discontinue processing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i will use convert to value with schema/dictionary or use a java service with bufferedReader.

Do you need all the contents of the file or can you perform processing on these batch lines? Because 100 MB CSV can cause memory problems

[iterate over file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggTIc.png)